# Comments for a class that isn't an entity

Tags: comments, class

According to Java's commenting conventions, classes comments should describe a "thing", rather than "actions". It is easy when the class IS a thing (ex. a Clown), but what if it isn't?

In this case, the `ShapeProvider` is a proxy class that requests "stringified" `Strings`  to a small server application via the `get` method. The string is then parsed to build a `BaseShape` object, that is returned to the client of the service. The client simply draws the shape on a small GUI. This is a school work, so I'd want my comments to be as close as possible to the Java conventions.

```
/**
* How should I comment this?
*/
public class ShapeProvider extends ServerConnection{

    /**
    * Method comment that is okay.
    */
    public BaseShape get(){
       //Requests the shape
       //Parses the response
       //Use a Factory to create an instance of BaseShape
       //Return it
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone finds a better name for the question, don't hesitate to change it!

Comment: I think you need to provide more context. It's difficult to come up with documentation for something when we only have the class name and a method signature.

Comment: I'll edit! I was looking for a general guideline but if it isn't easy to figure I'll add more context to be more specific.

Comment: Abstract things are still things. Ask any mathematician.

Comment: what is in [Class/Interface Specification section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-142372.html#class) of official _Requirements for Writing Java API Specifications_ that you don't understand? FWIW word  "thing" isn't mentioned there, where did you get that idea?

Comment: I got this information in [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### But your ShapeProvider *is* a thing!

How comes, you don't see it as a thing? Your `ShapeProvider`is a someone who is responsible for providing you shapes while relying on `X` and `Y` to do so. I think that is a acceptable commentation regarding the commenting conventions.

**But** it shows you, that this code is actually not very well designed or named. Because why on earth would a `ShapeProvider` *extend* a ServerConnection? That's just wrong. A `ShapeProvider`rather relies on some repository or repository connection and uses it to create the shapes. `extends` should therefore not be used for this purpose at all!

Comment: Your answer made me realize that my ShapeProvider **is** a repository! But I should remove the server's connection code from that repository to put it somewhere else. Did I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: Make your repository not extending a connection but using it. Pass the connection into the constructor and let the repository tell its connection to fetch the information the repository needs to fullfill its tasks.